# prevent \vadjust from influencing bottom line

Tags: vertical-alignment

In most circumstances, a `\vadjust{\someverticalmaterialofzeroheight}` is "harmless", but not so if it is issued in the bottom line of a page:

```
Top of page\par\vfill Bottom of page\par
```

and

```
Top of page\par\vfill Bottom\vadjust{} of page\par
```

differ slightly: The descender of the "g" extends below the official textarea bottom in the first example, but not in the second.
Is there any way to prevent this effect?

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: What are you entering in `\vadjust`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know your text is normal text with no large inline images or math then you can assume that the depth of the line is less than that of `\strut` so you can make sure it *is* `\strut` then compensate.

```
Top of page\par\vfill Bottom\strut\vadjust{\nobreak\vskip-\dp\strutbox\hbox{}} of page\par
```